# One xml to many java file?

Tags: android

I have two activities called Home and Options. 
Home contains 6 buttons : Doctors - Appointments...etc
Options contains 3 buttons : Add - Edit/Delete - List.

Options is a common layout it means I want it to open when pressing on Doctors and Appointments. 
But the problem is that I want to write on the buttons respectively "Add doctor - Edit/Delete doctor - List doctor" in options.xml if the pressed button in Home was Doctors and "Add appointment - Edit/Delete appointment - List appointment" in options.xml if the pressed button in Home was appointment.

The point is to reduce the number of activities so that instead of creating 6 activities with the same format, Can I just write text in buttons depending on the previous activity?
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send information with the intent to start the new activity.

```
public void onDoctorClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("button_text_1", "Add doctor");
     intent.putExtra("button_text_2", "Edit/Delete doctor");
     intent.putExtra("button_text_3", "List doctor");
     startActivity(intent);
}

public void onAppointmentClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("button_text_1", "Add appointment");
     intent.putExtra("button_text_2", "Edit/Delete appointment");
     intent.putExtra("button_text_3", "List appointment");
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then you can get this information in your new activity and set the text of your buttons:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
button1.setText(extras.getString("button_text_1"));
button2.setText(extras.getString("button_text_2"));
button3.setText(extras.getString("button_text_3"));
```

EDIT

You can also send just one String to indicate what button started the activity

```
intent.putExtra("type", "doctor")
```

and then check ik in your second activity:

```
switch(getIntent().getExtras().getString("type")) {
case "doctor":
     button1.setText(R.string.doctor);
     break;
case "appointment":
     button1.setText(R.string.appointment);
     break;
}
```

Comment: Since I am trying to make my app multi languages, I tried to get the message from string like that :
intent.putExtra("button_text_1", R.string.apppointment);
But by this way the message does not appear. Is that any solution ?

Comment: @user3552658 String should be with a capital S. I also updated my answer to show another option which could be helpful if you use Strings from resource.

Comment: When I change string to String this error shows :
-Create constant 'String' in type 'R'
-Create field 'String' in type 'R'

This is my code :

Options :
Intent intent = new Intent(options.this, register.class);
intent.putExtra("msg1", R.string.addingdoctor);
intent.putExtra("msg2", R.string.add);
startActivity(intent);

register :
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
sign.setText(extras.getString("msg1"));
btnReg.setText(extras.getString("msg2"));

Before adding R.string.something all was fine and all strings was showing But now no one is showing
Your code give me error on capital String

Comment: Have you added your strings to the strings.xml file in res -> values ?

Comment: yes , like that :
<string name="listpatient">List patients</string>

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should not be a capital S. Just look at the EDIT in my answer for the best method.